# Different roles attributes with CanCan, Devise and ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin, cancan

I've discovered yesterday a tutorial that explains how to implement a role based single user model with Devise, ActiveAdmin and CanCan : http://renisoft.com/devise-activeadmin-cancan-single-user-model/. Yet, I'm new to rails, and I was wondering if it is possible to implement such a solution with roles that have different attributes. For instance, my users will have email, forename, surname, password and will share it with the other roles. But my seller role will have many attributes, my admin and my buyers will have others. Is it something possible to implement with those ruby gems ?

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Users and roles are two different things. Roles haven't got any attributes, but Users have.

However check this:

Rolify is a great Role management library for rails: https://github.com/EppO/rolify

Comment: In this tutorial (https://github.com/EppO/rolify/wiki/Tutorial), Forum seems to have it's own model, but not it's attributes.

Comment: "..seller role will have many attributes.." - I don't get this. Do you want to manage roles on attribute level?

Comment: I want to have users with those attributes: email, surname, forename, civility, phone, password. Then freelancers with different attributes: siren, experience etc. Employeurs with other attributes: society, siren_company, etc. I was thinking to use devise, ActiveAdmin and CanCan. Freelancers and prestataires would be Roles, with Users attributes, and their own.

Comment: I do have the same requirement .. can you please suggest me how to do this

Comment: I have 2 roles in my application except admin , those are client and advertiser. apart from the user model fields I have individual fields for client model and advertiser model .so how can I render those fields based on the roles while creating them from active admin. please help me with this.